# Can't figure out error in Eclipse

Tags: c++

I am having a problem with my program. I am using Eclipse, and I haven't been able to figure what these errors mean. I have been looking for awhile and cannot find my error. I have attached my two classes that show errors and the problem list when I build the file (I couldn't find the #endif statement into the screenshot for TransitionTable). Thanks for the help.

In the first class, it gives me an error in the constructor:

```
no match for call to `(TranslationTable<int, std::string>) (std::basic_istream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&)'

#ifndef TRANSLATOR_H_
#define TRANSLATOR_H_
#include "TranslationTable.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <fstream>

template<typename Key, typename Value>
class Translator
{
    private:
        TranslationTable<std::string,int> Table1;
        TranslationTable<int,std::string> Table2;
        Key getKey();
        Value getValue();

    public:
        Translator();
        Translator(Key key,Value value);
        Translator(std::istream& file);
};

template<typename Key, typename Value>
Translator<Key,Value>::Translator()
{
    return;
}

template<typename Key, typename Value>
Translator<Key,Value>::Translator(std::istream& file)
{
    Table1(file); // gives me error here
    Table1.fillTable(file);
    Table2(file); // same error here
    Table2.fillTable(file);

}


#endif /* TRANSLATOR_H_ */
```

This is the second class with an error, and it give me an error will looping through the array:

```
no match for 'operator*' in '**(((TranslationTable<int, std::string>*)this)->TranslationTable<int, std::string>::kP + (+(((unsigned int)i) * 8u)))'



#ifndef TRANSLATIONTABLE_H_
#define TRANSLATIONTABLE_H_
#include "KeyValuePair.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

template<typename Key, typename Value>
class TranslationTable
{
    private:
        int numPairs;
        KeyValuePair<Key,Value> *kP;

    public:
        TranslationTable();
        TranslationTable(std::istream& is);
        void fillTable(std::istream& is);
        Value getValue(Key myKey) const;
};

template<typename Key, typename Value>
TranslationTable<Key,Value>::TranslationTable()
{
    return;
}

template<typename Key, typename Value>
TranslationTable<Key,Value>::TranslationTable(std::istream& is)
{
    numPairs = 0;
    is >> numPairs;
    kP = new KeyValuePair<Key,Value>[numPairs];
}

template<typename Key, typename Value>
void TranslationTable<Key,Value>::fillTable(std::istream& is)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < numPairs; i++)
    {
        is >> *kP[i]; // error here
    }
}

template<typename Key, typename Value>
Value TranslationTable<Key,Value>::getValue(Key myKey) const
{


}

#endif /* TRANSLATIONTABLE_H_ */
```

Comment: Post the *actual* error message and relevant code into the question. Also, try to summarize the problem in the title .. usefully. If you *could* figure out the error, you wouldn't be asking this question :D

Comment: Please copy paste the errors themselves and the code (or subset if possible) here. Showing us wavy lines and screenshots of the problems window with the error message cut off, is frustrating at best..

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to type `Translator T1(file);` instead of just `T1(file)`, and similarly with `T2`

And you don't need the `*` in `*kP[i]`. It is already refering to the i-th element.

After that you need to define an `operator>>` for the class `KeyValuePair` to get `is >> kP[i];` to work.

```
istream& operator >>(istream &is,KeyValuePair &obj)
{
        ...
      return is;
}
```

Comment: I got the problem with the T1 and T2, I did T1 = TranslationTable<std::string,int>(file); But the kP still is not working either way with or without the *.

Comment: @BrentMitchell what is the error without the `*` ? missing `operator>>` ?

Comment: For the statement "is >> kP[i]" it shows:  no match for 'operator>>' in 'is >> *(((TranslationTable<int, std::string>*)this)->TranslationTable<int, std::string>::kP + (+(((unsigned int)i) * 8u)))'